# Theme FINALSKINFILE cannot be found in the application or global theme directories

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am getting this error

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Theme 'FinalSkinFile' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.

[image]

while running a site using IIS, although finalskinfile exists and I downloaded ASP.net features and roles.
Microsoft .NET framework version: 4.0.30319 ; ASP.NET version:4.7.3930.0

Comment: Please verify that you have a sub directory named `FinalSkinFile` and the necessary files in the App_Themes directory.

Comment: @samwu I did, the directory exists and the file as well.

Comment: This error occurs when the App_Themes folder is missing from your "wwwroot" directory (or Virtual Directory / Application) and prevents you from logging into your Admin Area, can you share your project structure and web.config file?